# How to reduce space between axis bar and first/last tick in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I am using tikzpicture to create a plot. My ojective is to reduce the space  between both vertical bars and first and last point. I understand that the space is evenly divided, but is it possible to reduce half the space in first and last point adjace to vertical bars only?
Plus, how can I add a small dash along with x-axis that points to xlables?

Here is my sample figure.
[image]

My **MWE** is

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis, 
    height=5cm,
    width=14.90cm,
    grid=both,
    max space between ticks=40, % To control the number of major ticks
    xlabel={Feature Patterns},
    ylabel={Accuracy},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    xtick={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I},
    xticklabel shift={.5cm},
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    yticklabels={0\%,10\%,20\%,30\%,40\%,50\%,60\%,70\%,80\%,90\%,100\%},
    legend pos=south east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
 
\addplot[ 
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
(10,83.88)(20,70.36)(30,44.28)(40,30.68)(50,84.30)(60,70.42)(70,44.26)(80,84.50)(90,84.60) };

\addplot[ 
    color=brown,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
(10,85.29)(20,66.21)(30,42.14)(40,30.39)(50,84.98)(60,64.39)(70,39.3)(80,84.02)(90,83.48) };

\addplot[ 
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
(10,78.29)(20,60.37)(30,39.79)(40,28.25)(50,77.03)(60,59.41)(70,38.95)(80,76.12)(90,76.03)};

\legend{1,2,3}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

After adjusting xmin=5 and xmax=95, the result is as follows:
[image]

I have pointed with red line(apologies) that the data points of both ends are not aligned with their X_labels.

Comment: You have set that distance yourself, by defining the axis limits with `xmin=0,xmax=100`. For the last part, are you after `xtick align=outside`?

Comment: No I do not want to join the data point of A and I with the vertical bar, I want to keep some space between them. Can you please guide how can I do that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Currently you have `xmin=0` and the first tick at x=10. If you set `xmin=5` instead, the distance between the axis box and the first tick will be halved.

Comment: And yes, for last part, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I agree and I have tried this before, but the problem is that *A* will not be aligned to the new position data point.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you change to `xmin=5, xmax=95` and show a screenshot of the output?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the screen shot just like you asked. I hope that clears the problem.

Comment: It's clear what the problem is, but I have no idea why it occurs. I don't see the same thing, but the expected output (e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/read/nvzsnkzbtjdr, will delete this project later).

Comment: Anees: For clarity, perhaps you could add the complete code that gives you the output in the question. Including documentclass, I just tested with the standard `article`.

Comment: I'd say that the output results from changing the x values of the first and last **data points** instead of changing `xmin`/`xmax` ...